# Matlab keeping a number of iterations in a for loop with two conditions

Tags: for-loop, iteration, conditional-statements, matlab-guide

The next Matab code, I need to keep the number of the last iteration:

```
A, B, arrays N numbers, increasing linearly.

for i 1:1:10

    if A(i) < B(i) && A(i+1) > B(i+1)

    number = i

    end

end

disp(i)
```

Unfortunately this code is not working.

I need to find and keep the number i, in which the relation A and B is changing.

any help is more than welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
A=rand(20,1);
B=rand(20,1);
for i=1:1:10

    if A(i) < B(i) && A(i+1) > B(i+1)
        number = i;
        break;  % Did you intend to stop when condition was satified?
    end

end
% Presumably you wanted to display the stored index 
% (although since we now break i and number will be the same)
disp(number)
```

BTW, Best to post code that can be run in your question.  Makes it easier for people answering to see the problem.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. Yes, I want to stop the iteration and the condition when I will find the right i. IT works! I never thought that it was so easy. Thank you!

Comment: ps. In Future, I will keep your advice. Thank you